# Android button no shadow with color theme

Tags: android, button, android-theme, android-styles

I have the following style that I am using to color a button:

```
<style name="AppTheme.PrimaryButton">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

Then I use that on my button:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.PrimaryButton" />
```

This is great but now I would like to modify my style to remove the shadow that appears behind the button.

I would like to modify my style rather than the button itself.

I tried to inherit from a borderless button:

```
<style name="AppTheme.PrimaryButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

With no luck.

I have also tried to set the button style in the style:

```
<style name="AppTheme.PrimaryButton">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">?attr/borderlessButtonStyle</item>
</style>
```

Again no luck.

Is there a way that I can maintain my colors and remove the shadow in my style?

Comment: try style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle" or android:stateListAnimator="@null" in button

Comment: have you use elevation in your button in layout file????that cause shadow in button.remove it.and try background :for  color Button

Comment: Would like to keep it as a reusable style in  a style file not inline.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the best way, but I was able to achieve what I wanted:

```
<style name="NoShadowButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
    <item name="android:stateListAnimator">@null</item>
</style>

<style name="PrimaryButton">
    <item name="colorAccent">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/NoShadowButton</item>
</style>
```

Then on button:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    android:theme="@style/PrimaryDarkButton" />
```